# DIfference between mentioned two queries in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, bigdata

Please explain the difference between two queries mentioned below. I am getting output for first query but no output for second. Thanks in advance.

***Table data:***

```
> db.inventory.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911ce218c302726ff998853"), "item" : "journal", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5 }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 15 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911ce218c302726ff998854"), "item" : "notebook", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 5 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911ce218c302726ff998855"), "item" : "paper", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 60 }, { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 15 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911ce218c302726ff998856"), "item" : "planner", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 40 }, { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 5 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911ce218c302726ff998857"), "item" : "postcard", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 15 }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 35 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911ce948c302726ff998858"), "item" : "journal", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5 } ] }
```

**Query 1:**

```
 > db.inventory.find( { "instock": { $elemMatch: { qty: 5, warehouse: "A" }}} )
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911ce218c302726ff998853"), "item" : "journal", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5 }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 15 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911ce948c302726ff998858"), "item" : "journal",    "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5 } ] }
```

***Query 2:***

```
> db.inventory.find( { "instock.qty": { $elemMatch: { $gt: 10, $lte: 20 } } } )
```

**Output:**

No output

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch)

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field
>   with at least one element that matches all the specified query
>   criteria.

Point to note the `field` should be an array.

The correct syntax for second query for querying on embedded fields `qty` inside array is

```
db.inventory.find( { "instock": { $elemMatch: { qty: { $gt: 10, $lte: 20 } } } } )
```

You should have a document like below with `qty` as array field for your current second query to return results.

```
{ "item" : "journal", "instock" : [ { "qty" : [ 5, 15 ] }, { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 5 }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 15 }] }
```

Comment: Thanks @Veeram. so the issue was with "instock.qty". As it was not an array.. right ?